# SQL Server- SQL to write nested case in select statement or in where-on clause?

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-server-2012, case, sql-server-2016

SQL query

```
select 
    case 
       when t2.property = 'TEST_1' and
            (t3.ltype like case when t3.lvalue=t1.DMetd and t3.ltype not in ('STATE','CITY') then t3.ltype end) 
          then t3.ltext 
          else null 
    end as myMethod
from  
    table1 t1 
join
    table2 t2 on t1.wid = t2.w_id 
left join
    tabl3 t3 on t3.lvalue = t2.mymethod
```

My `CASE` statement:

```
(t3.ltype like case when t3.lvalue=t1.DMetd and t3.ltype not in ('STATE','CITY') then t3.ltype end
```

In my query shall I write case statement in select clause, or in where or on clause?

Sample data:

In table3 I have columns like this

```
ltext, lvalue, ltype, care, cr, method1, effective care, cr, newmethod, 
urgent, UR, newmethod
```

I need to pick row

```
effective care, cr, newmethod
```

and I need to ignore row

```
care, cr, method1
```

table2 I need to check first

```
ON (t3.lvalue = t2.mymethod)
```

t2 has column `mymethod` with values like CR,AR,UR

table1 - column `Dmethd` has values like CR,AR,UR

[image]

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server? Don't add tags for databases you don't use.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer to me is it depends on what is semantically more representative of the conceptual reality you are modelling.

If your returned columns need to be manipulated to return values that formulated from underlying data using various functions, then put the case statements in the SELECT. If, however, the CASE statements are used as part of a data selection process that filters records, then put the CASE statements there. If the CASE statements help to define how tables are related together, then put them in the JOIN statement.